# Why is magento breking apart this h1?

Tags: extensions, code

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?> - <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></h1>
```

It's breaking it down like this

TITLE -

short_desc

Edit:
We've figured out that it has something to do with the Cart2Quote extension we are using. For some reason whenever we try and get the short description it just won't work. It works on our other template files.

Not sure if anyone has had this problem before.

Comment: Welcome to SE @Enigma. Most likely you haven't wrapped it by `<?php` tag. Please add more info. Probably full block of code from your `.phtml` file.

Comment: We've figured out that it has something to do with the Cart2Quote extension we are using. For some reason whenever we try and get the short description it just won't work. It works on our other template files.

Comment: Great, now you should add your own answer and mark that as solved.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is removing one line break after `?>` therefore it is not the PHP tag.

If we are talking about html source code I would assume short_descriptions starts with a line break.

If we are talking about rendered html I would assume short_descriptions starts with a `<br />`